# How to redirect to user profile page after log in?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm looking for a way to redirect to the user profile page after log in. The problem I'm facing is that I can figure out how to pass the user_id into the url to get the redirection to complete.

I understand that this is a common issue and I've tried following many suggested solutions I found from other people's issues, however none have allowed me to find a solution. As I pointed out in the comments, the reason for having a user_id in the url path is due to the nature of the app which allows users to view each other's profile page.

```
<div class='registration'>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'auth_login' %}">{% csrf_token %}

        <p> &nbsp;{% trans form.username.label_tag %} &nbsp;{{ form.username }}</p>

        <p> &nbsp; {% trans form.password.label_tag %} &nbsp; {{ form.password }}</p>

       <p>{% blocktrans %}<a href="{{ auth_pwd_reset_url }}">Forgot</a> your password? </br>
        <a href="{{ register_url }}">Need an account</a>?{% endblocktrans %}</p>

    <input class='login-button' type="submit" value="{% trans 'login' %}" />
    <input class= 'login-button'type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

```
    path('profile/<int:user_id>', core_views.user_profile, name='profile'),
```

Things I've tried

- (LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/')- this gave me a 404 error.
  -(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/')- this gave me a NoReverseMatch error.
- input class= 'login-button'type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url profile request.user_id %}"
- I've tried making a login in view but that didn't work either.

I've been stuck for a while on this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The typical solution is to not put the userID in the url at all, but instead store it in the session.  That way the profile url for all users is the same: `/profile`.  Are you able to use this approach?

Comment: I was definitely thinking about following that approach. I think the issue is that part of my app, which is a mentor/mentee app allows users to view each others profile pages. I'm not sure how I would go about that if I eliminated the user_id from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the same function and then set the `user_id` to `request.user.id` if it is not passed

```
path('profile/', core_views.user_profile, name='profile'),
path('profile/<int:user_id>/', core_views.user_profile, name='profile-view'),

def user_profile(request, user_id=None):
    if user_id == None: user_id = request.user.id
    ... now continue as before
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I appreciate your answer :)